# wlst for OSB operation

Tags: osb, wlst

I need to retrieve the statistics of OSB services at the operation level.
Please be noted we already have a script to do the same at the service level (inbound/outbound).

We need to invoke the below API it seems, please let us know if someone knows to do it.

" Statistics details for Resource Type – WEBSERVICE_OPERATION
This resource type provides statistical information pertaining to WSDL operations. Statistics are reported for each defined operation.

The following statistics are reported.

Table 2-3 WEBSERVICE_OPERATION Statistics
Statistic Name
Type
elapsed-time
interval
message-count
count
error-count
count "

We are doing R & D in parallel, will update this thread for any.